# Export Separate Json for each row in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have used this VBA code that export rows in excel to Json file. It's working fine however, I would like to export each row to Json file separately with the file name exported from Column A as currently it puts all Json in one big file.

```
Public Sub tojson()
    savename = "exportedxls.json"
    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & savename
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)
    lcolumn = wks.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lrow = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim titles() As String
    ReDim titles(lcolumn)
    For i = 1 To lcolumn
        titles(i) = wks.Cells(1, i)
    Next i
    Print #1, "["
    dq = """"
    For j = 2 To lrow
        For i = 1 To lcolumn
            If i = 1 Then
                Print #1, "{"
            End If
            cellvalue = wks.Cells(j, i)
            Print #1, dq & titles(i) & dq & ":" & dq & cellvalue & dq
            If i <> lcolumn Then
                Print #1, ","
            End If
        Next i
        Print #1, "}"
        If j <> lrow Then
            Print #1, ","
        End If
    Next j
    Print #1, "]"
    Close #1
    a = MsgBox("Saved as " & savename, vbOKOnly)
End Sub
```

Here is an example of my excel sheet
[image: Excel Example]

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is? What is keeping you from doing that?

Comment: Hi Geert, 
Thank you for your response. I am not able to amend the code to make it save as a file for each row. I wonder if you can help.

Comment: I'm afraid you are at the wrong place. This website is not for hiring help, but a technical website where programmers can ask questions about problems they face. If you have an actual specific question about the code writing then please edit your question and clarify that. If you are looking for someone to solve your problem for you, you should look for a website where you can hire programmers. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question